# Enable vi mouse wheel scrolling using bash on ubuntu on windows 10

Tags: bash, vim, windows-10, vi, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using bash on ubuntu on windows 10 and would like to enable scrolling using the mouse wheel in vi or vim. I've tried entering the following command in vim and added it to the .vimrc file and /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim

```
set mouse=a
```

However I still can't scroll with the mouse.

Comment: "I'm using bash on ubuntu on windows 10" -> Ehm, what? Also, your question is confusing, first you say you want to "enable scrolling" and then you state twice that this works? ("I still can scroll" and "the mouse wheel does work in the terminal")? What *exactly* isn't working where?

Comment: Facing the same issue here. Lol @ the close votes.. for everyone living under  a rock: [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about).

Comment: I think one possible solution may be to install an x server. Ive seen some articles mention Xming X server for windows but I have hesitated to delve into this possibility. Id like to know if anyone tries it though! For now I'm just using notepad++ to edit my code and using the terminal to browse and compile like I normally would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and simple answer:

If you use [mintty/wsltty](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty) it works just fine!

Comment: `set mouse=a` in `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` is a much better solution.

Answer (score 17):

I added this to my `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`, and it worked:

```
set mouse=a
map <ScrollWheelUp> <C-Y>
map <ScrollWheelDown> <C-E>
```

Comment: This is a much simpler solution than install WSLtty. Thanks.

Comment: my installation didn't include that file but it does work once added.

Comment: Brilliant. Just a note though, you can use `/home/<your username>/.vimrc` file as well to add these configurations.

Answer (score 3):

You have done, properly, all you can in `vim` and the problem is with your terminal emulator.

Mouse wheel scrolling through the scrollback buffer of a terminal emulator is a function of the terminal emulator which is consuming the mouse events.  You are wanting to send these events to the application (`vim`) hooked to the terminal.

Most terminal emulators have a way to enable the passthrough of mouse events when in "Application Key Mode" or "Alternate Screen".  Most also support using a modifier key (like holding ALT) that will passthrough the mouse events as you wish.

Comment: Holding any of `Ctrl/Alt/Shift` while scrolling doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Vim may not have been compiled with mouse support. See if you can get `gvim`. It contains a graphical version of Vim. Depending on your distribution it may also contain the terminal `vim` with almost all features enabled, including mouse support.

To check for mouse support in Vim, enter `:version` and check whether `+mouse` is in the list of features.

Comment: It's whatever compiled version that comes included with "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows",  which does seem to have `+mouse`: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11137205/x/tQhEBfNU.png .

gVim will need to have an X server installed, which is probably a whole new can of worms, seeing how broken everything is currently.